# Problem parsing list of companies with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I could parse the list of S&P500 companies with following codes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

def get_sp500_info():
    resp = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    stocks_info = []
    tickers = []
    securities = []
    gics_industries = []
    gics_sub_industries = []
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        security = row.findAll('td')[1].text
        gics_industry = row.findAll('td')[3].text
        gics_sub_industry = row.findAll('td')[4].text
    
        tickers.append(ticker.lower().replace(r"\n", " "))
        securities.append(security)
        gics_industries.append(gics_industry.lower())
        gics_sub_industries.append(gics_sub_industry.lower())
    
    stocks_info.append(tickers)
    stocks_info.append(securities)
    stocks_info.append(gics_industries)
    stocks_info.append(gics_sub_industries)
    
    stocks_info_df = pd.DataFrame(stocks_info).T
    stocks_info_df.columns=['tickers','security','gics_industry','gics_sub_industry']
    stocks_info_df['seclabels'] = 'SP500'
    return stocks_info_df

def open_in_excel(dataframe):
    xw.view(dataframe)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    open_in_excel(get_sp500_info())
```

Now I would like to parse list of Russel3000 companies with basically the same codes as above. And it doesn't work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

def get_russel3000_info():
    resp = requests.get("https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239714/ishares-russell-3000-etf#holdings")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    stocks_info = []
    tickers = []
    securities = []
    gics_industries = []
    
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'display product-table border-row dataTable no-footer'})

    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:           #Line A
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        security = row.findAll('td')[1].text
        gics_industry = row.findAll('td')[2].text

        tickers.append(ticker.lower().replace(r"\n", " "))
        securities.append(security)
        gics_industries.append(gics_industry.lower())
        
    stocks_info.append(tickers)
    stocks_info.append(securities)
    stocks_info.append(gics_industries)
    
    stocks_info_df = pd.DataFrame(stocks_info).T
    stocks_info_df.columns=['tickers','security','gics_industry']
    stocks_info_df['seclabels'] = 'Russel3000'
    return stocks_info_df

def open_in_excel(dataframe):
    xw.view(dataframe)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    open_in_excel(get_russel3000_info())
```

I can't understand why it works with S&P500 but not with Russel3000.
At "Line A" I would get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

It shouldn't return "None".
I am thankful for any pointer:-)

Comment: The table you're looking for is being dynamically created after the page loads from other resources.  You'll either need to monitor network traffic and/or view the source of the javascript on the page to see how it generates the data it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load tables directly into pandas:

```
df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies")
```

You can access the tables on the page with `df[0]`, `df[1]`, etc. In the case of `ishares.com` the particular table doesn't load because it is loaded locally through javascript. One solution is to use `Selenium` to do the job:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

url="https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239714/ishares-russell-3000-etf#holdings"
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
wd.get(url)
time.sleep(5) # sleep for a few seconds to allow loading the data
df = pd.read_html(wd.page_source)
```

`df[7]` is the table you're looking for:

|  | Ticker | Name | Sector | Asset Class | Market Value | Weight (%) | Notional Value | Shares | CUSIP | ISIN | SEDOL | Accrual Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAPL | APPLE INC | Information Technology | Equity | $560,367,328.56 | 5.16 | 5.60367e+08 | 4.38506e+06 | 037833100 | US0378331005 | 2046251 | - |
| 1 | MSFT | MICROSOFT CORP | Information Technology | Equity | $482,112,717.24 | 4.44 | 4.82113e+08 | 2.03475e+06 | 594918104 | US5949181045 | 2588173 | - |
| 2 | AMZN | AMAZON COM INC | Consumer Discretionary | Equity | $362,479,373.96 | 3.34 | 3.62479e+08 | 115214 | 023135106 | US0231351067 | 2000019 | - |
| 3 | FB | FACEBOOK CLASS A INC | Communication | Equity | $172,844,238.24 | 1.59 | 1.72844e+08 | 652464 | 30303M102 | US30303M1027 | B7TL820 | - |
| 4 | GOOGL | ALPHABET INC CLASS A | Communication | Equity | $168,815,957.22 | 1.55 | 1.68816e+08 | 81567 | 02079K305 | US02079K3059 | BYVY8G0 | - |

A better solution is to load the json file directly. As you can see when you inspect the website in Firefox or Chrome, the table data is loaded from this json url: `https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239714/ishares-russell-3000-etf/1467271812596.ajax?tab=all&fileType=json`. Loading this into pandas has the advantage of having the full 2866 entries in your dataframe in one go. We cannot load it directly into pandas because the file contains a UTF-8 BOM header, but this will work:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239714/ishares-russell-3000-etf/1467271812596.ajax?tab=all&fileType=json"
r = requests.get(url)
json = json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8-sig'))
df = pd.DataFrame(json['aaData'])
```

Output:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAPL | APPLE INC | Information Technology | Equity | {'display': '$560,367,328.56', 'raw': 560367328.56} | {'display': '5.16', 'raw': 5.15741} | {'display': '560,367,328.56', 'raw': 560367328.56} | {'display': '4,385,064.00', 'raw': 4385064} | 037833100 | US0378331005 | 2046251 | {'display': '127.79', 'raw': 127.79} | United States | NASDAQ | USD | 1 | USD | - |
| 1 | MSFT | MICROSOFT CORP | Information Technology | Equity | {'display': '$482,112,717.24', 'raw': 482112717.24} | {'display': '4.44', 'raw': 4.43718} | {'display': '482,112,717.24', 'raw': 482112717.24} | {'display': '2,034,746.00', 'raw': 2034746} | 594918104 | US5949181045 | 2588173 | {'display': '236.94', 'raw': 236.94} | United States | NASDAQ | USD | 1 | USD | - |
| 2 | AMZN | AMAZON COM INC | Consumer Discretionary | Equity | {'display': '$362,479,373.96', 'raw': 362479373.96} | {'display': '3.34', 'raw': 3.33612} | {'display': '362,479,373.96', 'raw': 362479373.96} | {'display': '115,214.00', 'raw': 115214} | 023135106 | US0231351067 | 2000019 | {'display': '3,146.14', 'raw': 3146.14} | United States | NASDAQ | USD | 1 | USD | - |
| 3 | FB | FACEBOOK CLASS A INC | Communication | Equity | {'display': '$172,844,238.24', 'raw': 172844238.24} | {'display': '1.59', 'raw': 1.59079} | {'display': '172,844,238.24', 'raw': 172844238.24} | {'display': '652,464.00', 'raw': 652464} | 30303M102 | US30303M1027 | B7TL820 | {'display': '264.91', 'raw': 264.91} | United States | NASDAQ | USD | 1 | USD | - |
| 4 | GOOGL | ALPHABET INC CLASS A | Communication | Equity | {'display': '$168,815,957.22', 'raw': 168815957.22} | {'display': '1.55', 'raw': 1.55372} | {'display': '168,815,957.22', 'raw': 168815957.22} | {'display': '81,567.00', 'raw': 81567} | 02079K305 | US02079K3059 | BYVY8G0 | {'display': '2,069.66', 'raw': 2069.66} | United States | NASDAQ | USD | 1 | USD | - |

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful:-) A question: How could you tell if a website  "loaded locally through javascript"? Thanks again

Comment: There are several pointers. First, the table data is not immediately visible when the site loads. Second, the data is not present in the source code. Third, you can see that it loads the data after having loaded the site when you [inspect the network activity](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network).